# JavaScript replace regex every occurence but the last?

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a way to use a regex with `replace` on every occurrence except the last?

For example, I want `"abc"` to become `"a|b|c"`.

I can do:

```
"abc".replace(/./g, "$&|");
```

But that results in `a|b|c|`. Is there a way to replace every occurrence except the last? Or to do *n* occurrences, rather than do all globally with `g`? Or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: In this case, you could just do `"abc".split("").join("|")`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead:

```
"abc".replace(/.(?!$)/g, "$&|"); // => "a|b|c"
```

Or even:

```
"abc".split("").join("|"); // => "a|b|c"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without regex:

```
var s = "abc";
var r = s.split('').join('|');
//=>"a|b|c"
```